# How to import regex in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

Is there any module named regex to use like : `regex.compile(pattern, string)`
i tried to import it like this: `import re, regex` and I found this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'regex'`

Comment: try `import re as regex` if you want to access it as `regex.`

Comment: Sure, it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

you need to import the python regex library :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

by doing: `import re` and then you can put any name you want like regex
such as `import re as regex`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
pattern=re.compile('apple')
result=pattern.findall('apple Dipendra apple')
print(result)
```

You cannot import packages the way you are importing. I guess your work can be done with the python inbuilt "re" package. Please take a look into the above code snippet by me for your reference

Comment: I already use it like that, think this is the solution : import re as regex